# DefaultMessageListenerContainer: is it possible to cache consumer when using global transactions

Tags: java, spring, jms, spring-integration, spring-jms

I am a newbie to `Spring` and `JMS`. I was doing some reading regarding Topic consumption and how this can cause some messages to be lost if `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` does not cache the cosumer. much better explain [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7883)

My understanding ( and i hope it is wrong) is that `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` can not cache the consumer when it is used with a `TransactionManager` (i.e. Atomikos). If this is right, how can i prevent `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` from lossing non-durable Topics messages as describe in the SPR-7883 in this scenario?

I hope someone can help me clarify this

Answer (score 1):

Don't disable the cache as explained in the linked issue? You should probably switch to a durable subscriber in your case. What's wrong with that?